# In Cocoa on OS X, what use interface component allows the user to select a new file?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, openfiledialog, nsopenpanel

I understand how to use an `NSOpenPanel` to allow the user to select one or more existing files or directories, using a filename suffix. E.g.:

```
NSOpenPanel *openPanel = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];
openPanel.canChooseFiles = YES;
openPanel.canChooseDirectories = NO;
openPanel.allowsMultipleSelection = NO;
openPanel.allowedFileTypes = @[@"sqlite3"];
```

However, I would like to know if there is a component that allows the user to select a **new** file. That is, they select a directory from the `NSOpenPanel` and type in a filename. Is there a pre-built component for this?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `NSSavePanel` component.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSSavePanel_Class/index.html.